# Is the function analytic or not?

Tags: analysis

Whether the function $Si(x)=\int \frac{\sin x}{x}$ is analytic or not?

Please give the proof of the question.

Comment: Hint: What does its Taylor series look like?

Answer (score 2):

The function $z\mapsto \sin(z)/z$ is entire if you define it to be 1 at 0.  Any entire function $f$ has an entire function $F$ so that $F'= f$.  So the answer is, "Yes."

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it true that for any analytic function $f$ the function $g(x):=\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$, $g(0):=f'(0)$, is analytic as well? So $G$ is analytic.